# When assigning a pointer to structure pointer, mcu goes in to Hardfault Handler

Tags: pointers, structure, stm32

I am using STM32F072 mcu and IAR as compiler.

When I run the code below, it goes into hardfault handler. I couldn't figure out why is that.

```c
    uint8_t *ptr1;
    uint32_t *ptr2;
    uint32_t temp;

    typedef struct{
        uint8_t Data[10];
    } example_struct;

    example_struct sensor;

    sensor.Data[0] = 0xAA;

    ptr1 = &sensor.Data[0];  // here ptr1 is pointing 0xAA with no problem
    ptr2 = (uint32_t*) ptr1; // here *ptr2 is 0x000000AA, so there is no problem.
    temp = *ptr2;            // here mcu goes in to hardfault handler
```

Do you have any idea why I am having this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The code seems okay for me. Do you have any interrupt sources running?

Comment: chech what caused the HF.  I bet it is unaligned access. Check the `ptr2` (see if `((uint32_t)ptr1 & 3)` if non zero. If yes it is thealignmen problem

Comment: As P__J__ says it is probably an unaligned access. In any case case you would be better reading the value into a uint8_t and then copying into a uint32_t, otherwise your dereferenced pointer will include other values in the array and will also be unaligned for other indexes in the array (i.e. temp = *ptr1 )